# Quantify the comparison between two columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Column "a" contains, let's say, type of car and column "b" contains that car's color. what I need to do is format a table that shows the quantity of, for instance, "Blue Civics" so that I can compare that to "Blue Jeeps" and "Red Landrovers." does anyone know an easy way to do this without initializing a bunch of variables and making a bunch of if statements?

Basically, I'm going to have 4 types of car and each of those cars has 4 possible colors. Right now, I have something like this:

```
Dim HondaRed As Integer, HondaBlue As Integer
For Each a In ary
    On Error Resume Next
    cl.Add a, CStr(a)
    'if statements that ask if column "a" is is honda if column "b" is blue, then incramanets HondaBlue by 1'
Next a
```

I could do this in c++ no problem. The problem is, I'm still leraning VB so any help or resources to point me in the right direction would be grately appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to compare blue civics to "Blue Jeeps" and "Red Landrovers."  ?

Comment: Consider creating a Pivot Table or using VBA to create the Pivot Table.

Comment: @GowthamShiva I don't, I was just giving an example. I want to combine what is in column a with what is in column b then increment how many of those combined values exist.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent could you point me in the right direction in terms of where to look for information? I've never used pivot tables either

Comment: Google -> "how to use Excel pivot table" should do wonders (as would merely *trying* to play with one). And then use the macro recorder to get acquainted with the object model for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a VBA example, say we start with:

[image]

Here is some very simple code:

```
Sub TableMaker()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        ca = Cells(i, 1)
        cl = Cells(i, 2)
        If ca = "Honda" Then j = 2
        If ca = "Toyota" Then j = 3
        If ca = "Chevy" Then j = 4
        If ca = "Ford" Then j = 5
        If cl = "Blue" Then k = 5
        If cl = "Black" Then k = 6
        If cl = "Red" Then k = 7
        If cl = "White" Then k = 8
        'MsgBox j & vbCrLf & k & vbCrLf & Cells(j, k)
        Cells(j, k) = Cells(j, k) + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

The headers in the frequency table were added manually.  The ***i , j*** values in the `IFs` are based on the table's location.

**Using a Pivot Table is still the best approach.**

Comment: This is a much better method than I was planning, Thank you